# SQL IN Operator Query

Tags: sql, operator-keyword

I have a question on the sql IN query. For example you have table with columns id, amount name.

With a query:

```
  SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table WHERE id IN (101,101);
```

What I want with this is to add amount of a certain id. Whatever the id is inside the IN statement. If like this, two 101, amount of 101 + amount of 101.

The problem is it consider it is one instance. How do I do this? its suppose to be:

```
  SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table.........);
```

Which the sub select return "101, 101".

How

Comment: You need to explain **why** you need that.

Comment: what's the problem with this `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table.........);`?

Comment: its the same as SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table WHERE id IN (101,101); because the query return 101,101 which is correct. But, if it is summed up, the SUM statement considers id 101 and 101 as only 1 instance. I want it to consider it as two instance.

Comment: @zerkms I need this because I want to add the amount to whatever is selected by the subselect. Does not matter if an ID appears twice, 101 has an amount of 5. The parent query should return 10, which is 5 + 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(tbl.amount)
FROM tbl
JOIN (select 101 id UNION ALL
      select 101) InList on InList.id = tbl.id
```

Expand this way.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this

```
Select * From table1
inner join dbo.fnSplit(@ArgList, ',')
```

That would definitely work for me